# Prestashop register public hook for all modules

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have problem with my prestashop 1.6 theme and module. I need register a few hook (positions) for my theme. To theme I create own plugins and in it add these line:

```
public function install()
{
    Configuration::updateValue('TESTRTVTHEME_LIVE_MODE', false);

    return parent::install() &&
        $this->registerHook('header') &&
        $this->registerHook('backOfficeHeader') &&
        $this->registerHook('testHomeSearch') &&
        $this->registerHook('testHomeBasket') &&
        $this->registerHook('testMenu1') &&
        $this->registerHook('testMenu2') &&
        $this->registerHook('testMenu3') &&
        $this->registerHook('testMenu4') &&
        $this->registerHook('testMenu5') &&
        $this->registerHook('testMenu6') &&
        $this->registerHook('displayTwMenu6') &&
        $this->registerHook('testMenu7')
        ;
}
```

Next I add this lines to theme:

```
{hook h='displayLeftColumnZ' mod='blockcart'}
```

Okey, Now I need add custom place/position to display cart in my theme, I try to register theme hook and display it but it not works :(

Can you show my how I add a custom positions, add module to it and display in custom place in theme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is the following :

1. Add an entry in the DB table ps_hooks with all the information needed
2. In your theme (e.g product.tpl), call your hook using {hook h='myHook'}
3. In your module, add the following function to the main file (mymodule.php) :

   public function hookMyHook($params) {}

Then, you just have to write your rendering in this function and you're set.

The line `$this->registerHook('myHook')` in the `install()` function of the module is not declaring a new hook, but automatically hooks the module to this position.